# Deserialize JSON dictionary values with JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I use Json.NET library to deserialize JSON. For an abstract class `Foo` I have a custom `JsonConverter`. This is the way I have used it:

```csharp
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooJsonConverter))]
public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
```

So far so good. The problem arises when I use the Foo class in a Dictionary. This was my attempt:

```csharp
[JsonDictionary(ItemConverterType = typeof(FooJsonConverter))]
public Dictionary<string, Foo> MyFooDictionary { get; set; }
```

But the above gives the error:

> Attribute 'JsonDictionary' is not valid on this declaration type. It is
>   only valid on 'class, interface' declarations.

How to specify converter for Dictionary value?

Comment: Could you publish your Deserialization code ? or better a minimal working example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[JsonProperty]` instead of `[JsonDictionary]`.

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(FooJsonConverter))]
public Dictionary<string, Foo> MyFooDictionary { get; set; }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QJCtBg

Another alternative is to add your converter to the `JsonSerializerSettings` and pass that to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new FooJsonConverter());

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjType>(json, settings);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the attribute to your Foo class. This is probably because your Dictionary could contain two different types and the attribute would not know which one you are referring to.

```
[JsonDictionary(ItemConverterType = typeof(FooJsonConverter))]
public class Foo
{

    ...

}
```

Comment: Exception: "Type Foo is not a dictionary."